# Check if user object is set inside Symfony expression language annotation

Tags: php, symfony, security, expression

I am using the `@Security` annotation to control which roles have access to certain routes in my Symfony 3.4 application, it works when I am logged in however when the `user` object doesn't exist such as when the session times out I get the following exception thrown.

`Unable to get a property on a non-object.`

> vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ExpressionLanguage/ExpressionLanguage.php:78
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\ExpressionLanguage->evaluate('\'ROLE_MANAGER\'
>   in user.getRoles()',

My method definition looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/club/{id}/trophies", name="club_trophies", methods={"GET","POST"})
 * @IsGranted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
 * @Security("'ROLE_MANAGER' in user.getRoles()")
 * @param Club $club
 * @return Response
 */
public function trophies(Club $club): Response
{
```

Is there a way using the Symfony Expression Language, or similar, that I can check that `user` exists. Or is there a better way?

Comment: This isn't what you asked for, but have you considered setting `access_control` rules in `security.yml` to specify that a user must be `IS_AUTHENTICATED` for routes where you expect to have a user? I think this _should_ prevent the request even making it to the controller if a user isn't authenticated, thus solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you are not authenticated, the value of user is null, so it's normal that your check is throwing an exception (as you're trying to access the method getRoles() of a null object).

The proper ways to check if a user has a given role using annotations are :

```
@IsGranted("ROLE_MANAGER")
```

Or :

```
@Security("is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER')")
```

You can see more here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html